# Magento DB customer orders mapping

Tags: mysql, magento

How are Magento orders mapped to the customer? Does the order contain the customer ID or does the customer contain all their order ids? Trying to figure out if changing order numbers will mess up customer mapping.

Comment: When you say change the order ID's - what do you have in mind?

Comment: I added a prefix to them. Testing it on a test server using this SQL: UPDATE sales_flat_order_grid SET increment_id = CONCAT('BU', increment_id);
UPDATE sales_flat_order SET increment_id = CONCAT('BU', increment_id)

Comment: Try this: http://chilipepperdesign.com/2009/07/09/changing-magento-order-invoice-and-shipping-numbers/

Comment: I actually read that article already and used it to form my sql command. But it still doesn't answer the customer mapping issue :( Like if I change all the order numbers from the past.. will that mess up if I were to go into Joe Dirts past orders?

Comment: I think you'll be fine running that.  I have modified many things in the sales_flat_* tables with no ill effects.  Always back up your data first.

Comment: Yes, your right I see they are still mapped ! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me answer your questions at first

**How are Magento orders mapped to the customer?**

> Magento Orders are mapped to the customers using "**customer_id**" Foreign Key field in the order tables **"sales_flat_order","sales_flat_order_grid","sales_flat_order_address"**. And Customer entity has no reference to the orders in turn.

**Does the order contain the customer ID or does the customer contain all their order ids?**

> **Order only contains the customer ID not the other way around.** Basically Customer entity follows the EAV structure like products and categories.

**Now coming to your task of changing Order Numbers (technical field name increment_id).**

> Yes you can change the increment numbers of the order. You need to do that in two tables

```
1. sales_flat_order
2. sales_flat_order_grid
```

> Please make sure to **reset the order increment last id** of entity type id "5" which represents Order after completing your task of changing the order numbers. You should do this in the table "**eav_entity_store**"

Let me know if you need more information regarding this.

Comment: Thank you! :) For all those wondering, yes you can change the ID's and they will still be mapped to customer!